# Comparing strings not to match in bash

Tags: string, bash, compare

I have a var which should contain either one or other string value or exit the program.

The first one seems to work for me:

```
[ !"$JOB_FILE" == "all_jobs.pl" ] || [ !"$JOB_FILE" == "incomplete.out" ] && { echo -e "\n Only all_jobs.pl or incomplete.out are valid job files\n"; exit 127 ; }
```

However this second one does not:

```
[ "$JOB_FILE" != "all_jobs.pl" ] || [ "$JOB_FILE" != "incomplete.out" ] && { echo -e "\n Only all_jobs.pl or incomplete.out are valid job files\n"; exit 127 ; }
```

What is the difference between both NOT equal definitions.

Comment: You cannot use `!"$JOB_FILE" ...`, write a space between `!` and `"$JOB_FILE"`.

Comment: Thanks! Now with space both examples does not work. Can anyone suggest a working syntax for that?

Comment: You want `&&` not `||`. Everything will not match at least one of those names. Since it cannot be both strings.

Comment: Be careful about ordering of `&&` and `||` - `foo && bar || baz` is generally equivalent to `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi`, but due to evaluation/execution order, `foo || baz && bar` does not generally do what you might think it does - it's more like `if not foo; then if baz; then bar; fi; fi`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is the other way round.

You want to check if `JOB_FILE` is either "A" or "B". In the rest of cases, print an error message.

```
JOB_FILE  status
A         ok
B         ok
rest      error
```

Hence

```
A   B   (A or B)  !(A or B)    !A or !B         !A and !B
1   0       1         0       0 or 1 => 1      0 and 1 => 0
0   1       1         0       1 or 0 => 1      1 and 0 => 0
0   0       0         1       1 or 1 => 1      1 and 1 => 1
--------------------------------------------------------------
                              always true      just true if not A and not B
```

Where `1=True`, `0=False`.

After this taste of logic, what you need is:

```
[ ! "$JOB_FILE" == "all_jobs.pl" ] && [ ! "$JOB_FILE" == "incomplete.out" ] && { echo ... }
                                   ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the correct forms:

```
[ ! "$JOB_FILE" == "all_jobs.pl" ] && [ ! "$JOB_FILE" == "incomplete.out" ] && {
    echo -e "\n Only all_jobs.pl or incomplete.out are valid job files\n"
    exit 127
}

[ "$JOB_FILE" != "all_jobs.pl" ] && [ "$JOB_FILE" != "incomplete.out" ] && {
    echo -e "\n Only all_jobs.pl or incomplete.out are valid job files\n"
    exit 127
}
```

And when in Bash, this is better:

```
[[ $JOB_FILE != "all_jobs.pl" && $JOB_FILE != "incomplete.out" ]] && {
    echo -e "\n Only all_jobs.pl or incomplete.out are valid job files\n"
    exit 127
}
```

Or this:

```
shopt -s extglob  ## Not necessary on Bash 4.1 or newer.

[[ $JOB_FILE != @(all_jobs.pl|incomplete.out) ]] && {
    echo -e "\n Only all_jobs.pl or incomplete.out are valid job files\n"
    exit 127
}
```

Using `regex` is also possible but it's more difficult to escape.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a logic error. You want to execute your echo if *both* statements are true, yet you are using `||`. You really mean to be using `&&`.

```
if [[ "$JOB_FILE" != "all_jobs.pl" && "$JOB_FILE" != "incomplete.out" ]]; then 
   echo -e "\n Only all_jobs.pl or incomplete.out are valid job files\n"
   exit 127
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to rather check if the filename is the expected one and make use of logical OR to chain conditions:

```
[ "$JOB_FILE" = "all_jobs.pl" ] || [ "$JOB_FILE" = "incomplete.out" ] || { echo -e "\n Only all_jobs.pl or incomplete.out are valid job files\n"; exit 127 ; }
```